# Android maximum arraylist size

Tags: java, android

I am reading from `SQLite` in android some name of `Files`, I have like 3000 names that are added to an `ArrayList` but I discovered that I can't have more than 1000.
Is 1000 maximum size of an `ArrayList<String>` ? Searching over the internet I found that depends.

I found some math operations here (http://www.coderanch.com/t/524745/java/java/Maximum-capacity-arrayList-String-objects ) with 1000, and I found that the maximum capacity of an `ArrayList<String>` is given by Java Virtual Machine Memory.

Is there a way how to increase this ?

Comment: theoretically you are limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (in size). Then, of course, you have to keep in mind the heap

Comment: the maximum capicity of a `ArrayList` is given by the `int`. To be specific it´s `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8`, as it is defined in the constant `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` inside the `ArrayList`

Comment: You can try `android:largeHeap="true"` on your `application` **tag** in `Manifest` file.

Comment: My 2 cents: Filter your queries, to get less results basing on some parameters.

Comment: why do you want to read it into `ArrayList`?

Comment: Because it's easy to manage, add/remove, methods like size etc. Where else can I read ?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I am reading music files from cloud and put them in arrayList, after that I set my arraylist as adapter for RecyclerView, if a User have 5000 songs I can't limit him at 1000.

Comment: if you are using `RecyclerView` then use this: https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b, no need to store your data it in any indirect `ArrayList`, with it you can have as many songs as you want

Comment: `ArrayList` is a bad way to save alot of data. You could take a look at `LinkedList` because that doesn't have a maximum size.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on both adapter and LinkedList

Comment: `LinkedList` is not any different than `ArrayList`: both are just `List` implementations

Comment: Just use a cursorAdapter if you already got the db... You are describing the reason they exist..

Comment: `I am reading music files from cloud and put them in arrayList, after that I set my arraylist as adapter for RecyclerView, if a User have 5000 songs I can't limit him at 1000.` Well, basically the approach is wrong. I'd store the titles in a database, first. Then query the database and filter by: `artist name`, `album title`, `song title`, `genre`, ... and get only the few records needed. OR use pagination (to get, say, 250 records per page).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein `"I am reading from SQLite in android...`" i think OP reads the data from a local database

Comment: @pskink But he told me `I am reading music files from cloud  and put them in arrayList`

Comment: I have never really thought of the maximum size of an array, just build your own arraylist. that has no maxValue, i can help you with that

Comment: Reading files from cloud, adding them to SQLite database, need them to read from database and put the names into an ArrayList.

Comment: Reading files from cloud, adding them to SQLite database and passing the database `Cursor` to the adapter i linked in my previous comment (**not** putting the names into an `ArrayList`)

Answer (score 1):

I have created an `arrayList`, its unlimited. you can also manipulate it to your desire, its has all the basic features of an `arraylist`.

here is the code.

```
public class BetterArray<E> {

private E[] array;
private final int DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
private int size;

private void copyArray(E[] copyFrom, E[] copyTo) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= copyFrom.length-1; i++) {
        copyTo[i] = copyFrom[i];
    }
}

private void createAnotherArray(){
    int newSize = 2 * array.length;
    E[] newArray = (E[])(new Object[newSize]);
    copyArray(array, newArray);
    array = newArray;
}

public BetterArray() {
    array = (E[]) (new Object[DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE]);
    this.size = 0;
}


public E get(int index){
    if(index < 0 || index > size){
        throw new RuntimeException("index not valid");
    }
    else{
        return array[index];
    }

}


public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (size == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}



public void insert(int position, E element) {
    if(isFull())
        createAnotherArray();

    E previous_temp = get(position);
    array[position]= element;
    for(int k = position+1; k<= size; k++){
        E current_temp = get(k);
        array[k] = previous_temp;
        previous_temp = current_temp;
    }
    size++;
}

public void append(E element) {
    insert(size, element);
 }

public void remove(int index){
    for (int i = index; i <= size-1; i++){
        array[i] = get(i+1);
    }
    size--;
}

public void shift(E element){
    insert(0, element);
}



public boolean isFull() {
    if (size == array.length)
        return true;
    return false;

}

public int size(){
    return size;
}


public String toString(){
    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i= 0; i <= size-1; i++){
        returnString.append(get(i).toString() + ", ");
    }
    return returnString.toString();
}


//  public int index(E element){
//      return 1;
//  }


public void reverse(){
    E temp_storage;
    int halfSize = (size/2) ;
    for (int k= 0; k<= halfSize; k++ ){
        temp_storage = array[k];
        array[k] = array[size-k-1];
        array[size-k-1]  = temp_storage;
    }

}



  }
```